# Mail to a Friend: Opens a new window

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I found a job opening that suited my skill set rather well, and the skill set of a colleague that I know is actively looking.  So, I wanted to send them the information via mail.

If I click on the link, I'm taken to a new window.  If I Control+Click, I'm taken to a blank new tab.

[Here's the page.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/33679/web-developer-all-experience-levels-trifecta-technologies?a=DN5b26I)  I'm on Google Chrome 27.0.1453.65 beta, with Linux Mint 14.

Comment: What browser are you using? Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: That's a "mailto:" link. It works just fine, opening the mail client set as default on the machine..

Comment: It's the case that I do have a default mail client on my machine, but it's simply not opening it.  Typically my `mailto` links open in Thunderbird or GMail, depending on the machine I'm on.

Comment: Hmm... maybe because there's no recipient to the mailto? Worth trying to reproduce on jsfiddle, will do it tomorrow if I don't forget.

Comment: Actually, this is weird. When I click on `Mail to a friend` in Firefox, it opens a new (empty) Chrome tab.

Comment: @Makoto what happens when you click on a non-empty "mailto:" link? For instance, click on "contact us" at the bottom of http://careers.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Max:  Same thing.  Opens up in a new tab window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, "Mail to a friend" is a mailto: link. It's supposed to launch your local email client and fill in subject and body of a new email for you:

```
Subject: <job title>

Body:  
I found this job on Stack Overflow Careers:

<job title>
<page url>
<A few words from the job description>
```

Since this doesn't seem to work on your machine, an obvious workaround is to copy&paste and create the email manually. Also, re-installing the latest version of your email client could fix the problem.

Comment: A properly configured mail client does actually resolve the issue -mailto links work as expected.